# What ratio/percentage of a given object's molecules are absorbing/emitting photons at any given moment?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

I've read a couple of times in the past that when the Sun is shining on the grass, even under bright sunlight, only a fraction of the grass's molecules are interacting with the Sun's photons at any given moment.....

Is this true?  What is the fraction (for a brightly lit object)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a feeling for the involved numbers let us consider a how many atoms are on a surface of $1m^2$ of water.

- The mass density of water is $\rho_m = 1kg/dm^3 = 10^3 kg/m^3$.
- A single water molecule has the mass $m = 18 u$. Thus, $1mol$ has the mass $M=18g = 18\cdot 10^{-3}kg$. Therefore, we have $10^3/(18\cdot 10^{-3}) \approx 5 \cdot 10^{4} mol$ in $1m^3$ of water. Since $1mol$ consists of $N_A \approx 6.022 \cdot 10^{23}$ particles we have $N\approx 3\cdot 10^{28}$ molecules in $1m^3$ of water. Hence, the number density is given by $\rho_N = 3\cdot 10^{28}/m^3 = \frac{N}{V}$. This yields $V = N/\rho_N$.
- Next, we have to find a formula for the volume $V$. In order to do so, we assume that the molecules are packed like little spheres. The volume per molecule would be $V=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3 \approx 4 R^3$ -- we omit the packaging factor, which is approx 50%. Putting this into the upper formula we obtain the molecular radius $R$. It is approximately given by $4 R^3 = V = \frac{1}{\rho_n}$ which yields $R \approx 0.2 nm$.
- Now that we know the radius per molecule we can calculate the number of molecules on the surface. Taking only the area of $A=1m^2$ we have $N_s=\frac{A}{\pi R^2} \approx 8\cdot 10^{18}$ molecules building the surface. If we take a leaf and checks it's thickness, we will find that it is much thicker than $1\mu m$. Furthermore, if we would take a leaf and make it thinner, such that we can see some light through it, the thickness of the leaf would still be larger than $1\mu m$. Therefore, I suspect that  more than 1000 layers of molecules are used to fully absorb the light. Hence, the number of molecules involved in the absorption is probably something like $\tilde{N}_V \approx 10^{22}$.
- Next, we ask how much power the sun provides per square meter. Wikipedia says it around $1W/m^2$. Let's further assume that there are only red photons with wavelength $\lambda = 600nm$. The energy per photon would be $E = h \nu = h c/\lambda \approx 3.3 \cdot 10^{-19}J$. Thus, the number of photons per square meter and second is given by $1/E \approx 3 \cdot 10^{18}$. Thus approximately $40\%$ of all "surface molecules" $N_s$ and only $0.04\%$ of $\tilde{N}_V$ molecules interact once with a photon per second.
- Finally, we have to know the "dead time" for each molecule. I mean, if a molecule absorbs a photon, how long does it take to be available for the next photon? I don't know this dead time. However, if it is much shorter than $1s$, the effective percentage of interacting molecules becomes small. In contrast, if it takes a "long" time (compared to $1s$), we certainly have to take $\tilde{N}_V$ instead of $N_{s}$ as a reference.